# Setting up multiple instances of JBoss on the same machine

Tags: java, jboss

I've found next page in JBoss Community - http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/ConfigurePorts

There is next text:

---

Edit server/default/conf/bootstrap/bindings.xml

---

But I do not see file bindings.xml in JBoss 5.1.0 GA.

Does anyone know - what files should be changed in order to hav ability to start several instances of JBoss 5.1 on the same machine?

Comment: It's definitely there in 5.0.0, I'd be surprised if it wasn't there in 5.1.0

Answer (score 2):

The [Release Notes](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Release_Notes/510GA/readme.html) reference bindings.xml but it isn't there in the jdk6 or vanilla version.

I looks like the file has been moved and the structure modified. It now lives in:

${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml

Comment: Yes.

But as far as I can see not only bindings-jboss-beans.xml should be changed.

Next files should be changed too:

jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\ejb3-connectors-jboss-beans.xml 

jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml 

Is it correct?

Comment: Those are the files that I know of. Things do change between releases of JBoss so that makes things difficult to keep track of. I would start the first server, carefully go through the log files and verify which ports are being used. Make the modifications of the second server, start it and go through the log files. Some ports in use are also determined by which JBoss services you have enabled (Messaging, WS, etc.) and which profile you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following steps:

1) Copy the default folder with new name: instance name

2) In jboss-service.xml Uncomment the ServiceBindingManager mbean 
and change the ServerName to ports-01 or 02 or 03
e.g:ports-01 
and ports-01/02/03 configuration should be there in sample-bindings.xml(present in docs/examples/binding-manager)
And make the changes in all the ports mentioned under ports-01/02/03 tags, So that ports will not get conflict. Remember the server will run on the binding port like 8080/8180/8182.

from cmd promt go to the bin folder and run the instances with cmd:

run -c instancename

Thanks

Ankit Adlakha

Answer (score 1):

Use [the script that I wrote here](https://gist.github.com/4366912).    I requires you download libs from the YAJSW project, but it will run multiple instances straight out of the box  (as registered windows services) if you use one copy of my script per instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still stuck and can't find this file (it's in 5.0.1) then perhaps the defaults work for you.

I.e. I've set up multiple instances of JBoss 5.0.1 on one machine, using different ports.The 5.0 clustering guide explains how to do this for various scenarios. For example: See "section 1.1.2: Scenario 3: Two Nodes on a Single, Non-Multihomed, Server". https://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/JBossAS5ClusteringGuide

I didn't specify ports directly - but specified different pre-installed binding sets: e.g. via -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-default and -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01 and -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-02 ...