# jboss 5 changing default port

Tags: default, port, jboss5.x

I am trying to change the default port on my jboss server to port 80.

i have had a look around the web and i have had suggestions of editing this file jboss5\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml which is fine. changing this file alone still does not fix the issue.

There have also been suggestion to also change this file: jboss5\server\default\conf\bootstrap\bindings.xml Only problem is that i cant find this binding.xml

Is the binding.xml file a standard in JBoss 5? Or has it been renamed or changes location in JBoss 5.

Does anyone have any clear steps on changing the the default port from 8080 to 80.

Answer (score 14):

Can you try changing in `${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml`

Comment: in the end, I had to use bind to get the jboss to point to the port that i wanted.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

## ${JBOSS_HOME}\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml

For example, locate in the path:
**D:\jboss-5.0.0.CR2-jdk6\jboss-5.0.0.CR2\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar**,

search for the section:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
       connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Then, change the port number to the one you choose, for example: from: "8080" to "8090" as follows:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8090" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
       connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

I hope this would help you.

Answer (score 6):

This works on jboss-5.1.0.GA : 
Edit the file ${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml as follows ->
Change ${jboss.service.binding.set:ports-default} to 
${jboss.service.binding.set:ports-01}

This will change all defalt to default+100 port.
HTTP - > 8180 and so on.

Comment: Not able to locate this file in jboss-5.1.0.GA.

Answer (score 1):

It´s posible configure the ports as explained by peers in the next two files:

```
${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml

${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml
```

When the two configurations coexist Jboss works for the highest port, for example:

jbossweb.sar

```
Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8980" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
       connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
```

bindings-jboss-beans.xml

```
*${jboss.service.binding.set:ports-01}*
```

Jboss will run in port 8980

Answer (score 0):

another part could be

> Blockquote

**D:\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\server.xml**

> Blockquote

There

```
   *<Connector port=**"9090"** address="${jboss.bind.address}"    
     maxThreads="250" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
     emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
     enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
     connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />*
```

change the port above

Answer (score 0):

Just change the port number in the file

jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml

```
  <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="7070" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

In the above i have changed to 7070.

Answer (score 0):

Change the port number in the file ${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml. For example to 6060

```
  <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="6060" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

If for any reason dont works also change this another too. To the same port.

jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml