# How to change port on jboss version jboss-5.1.0.GA

Tags: jboss

I am trying to change the ports of my jboss server to run on port 80.

I've tried what feels like everything: editing the server.xml file, editing the C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\conf\bindingservice.beans\META-INF\bindings-jboss-beans.xml file to no avail.

Is there another way that I'm missing because I can only access my server via port 8082.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to change ${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml is the answer, as pointed out in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446400/jboss-5-changing-default-port)

But also change:
1. server.xml file at $jboss/server/jboss-ports-01/deploy/jbossweb.sar to the port you need

2. Verify also ${jboss.service.binding.set:ports-default} setting the correct binding as in ${jboss.service.binding.set:ports-PORT}

This [reference](https://www.techstacks.com/howto/change-port-numbers-in-jboss.html) brings more information about it as well.